# How to say 1-to-1 correspondence without causing any ambiguities?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following mathematics question,

> Each of integers from 1 to N is written on a separate piece of card.

It means that there are N cards, each with a distinct number.

Is it understandable if I say as follows in Japanese?

> 一からNまでの整数のめいめいはそれぞれ別のカードの一枚に書かれた。

Comment: I'm not a math specialist, but does the English sentence cause no ambiguities?

Comment: @brokenheadphones: I don't think it is ambiguous.

Comment: @brokenheadphones:  If you assume no duplicates, then I don't find the original sentence ambiguous.  But without that assumption, I think it could be seen as ambiguous, because then you could have N integers and >N cards.  For example, if there were 5 cards with '1' on it and all other integers from 2..N each appeared on only one separate card, then there would be a total of N+4 cards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In math questions, you would usually say like this:

> 「N枚のカードに、それぞれ１からNまでの異なる整数が書かれています。」
>   「N枚のカードに、それぞれ１からNまでの整数が１つずつ書かれています。」
>   or 「N枚のカードに、それぞれ１からNまでの異なる整数が１つずつ書かれています。」

It's also common to say like this:

> 「１からNまでの異なる整数が書かれたN枚のカードがあります。」
>   「１からNまでの整数が１つずつ書かれたN枚のカードがあります。」
>   or 「１からNまでの異なる整数が１つずつ書かれたN枚のカードがあります。」

I think you could also say like this:

> 「N枚のカードがあり、それぞれに１からNまでの異なる整数が書かれています。」
>   「N枚のカードがあり、それぞれに１からNまでの整数が１つずつ書かれています。」
>   or 「N枚のカードがあり、それぞれに１からNまでの異なる整数が１つずつ書かれています。」

or maybe like this, but this might be a bit wordy:

> 「N枚のカードがあり、それぞれに１からNまでのうちいずれかの整数が１つずつ書かれています。」

Answer (score 2):

> Each of（各々{おのおの}の） integers（整数（は or が）） from 1 to N（１からＮまでの） is written（書かれています） on a separate piece of card（それぞれ一枚のカードに）.

Then the following is the best translation.

> １からＮまでの各々{おのおの}の整数は、それぞれ一枚のカードに書かれています。

Your translation

> 一からNまでの整数のめいめいはそれぞれ別のカードの一枚に書かれた。

"整数のめいめい" is just acceptable as a translation by non-native Japanese speaker, at least you should use "めいめいの整数." "それぞれの整数" is far better.

---

If the N numbers (from 1 to N) are written in a card, it should be traslated into "１からＮまでの整数が、一枚のカードに書かれています。"
There is no need to use "各々," "それぞれ" or "めいめい" to describe this picture. There are two substances, one is a group of Numbers and the other is a card.

Answer (score 2):

I think "めいめい" is usually used for people to mean each person.

So, your sentence "一からNまでの整数のめいめいはそれぞれ別のカードの一枚に書かれた。" can be rephrased to read as follows:

"1からNまでの整数がそれぞれ別々のカードに書かれています".

Answer (score 1):

「カード一枚ずつに一つの整数」 means "one integer for each card" or "one integer per card".  The key you are looking for is "ずつに".

「1からNまで、カード一枚ずつに一つの整数 ...」